# Looking for reactjs vscode crud example code

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, serverless-framework, amazon-aurora

I would like to build a simple web app and learn reactjs at the same time, using vscode.  The web app I'd like to build is very simple- just one form with multiple sections, and in each section multiple elements can be added.  An example would be a section called 'People' and there is a form element for a person (first name, last name etc.).  If I add that person, it appears in a list under 'People' and I can add another Person.  Another section could be 'Cars', and I add a new car, etc. etc.  For each new person or car I add, it gets stored in a database and I can edit/update.

I've never build a reactjs app before but I've built many angularjs apps- but it's been a while.  I'm looking for an example or demo that uses reactjs to create a UI like this, and uses MySQL (or aurora) on the backend.

Ultimate goal is to get this app onto AWS.  Maybe using Serverless and graphql (also tools I've never used before).

Can anyone point me to an example or tutorial that might be a good fit for what I'm trying to learn?

And if there's a better place to post this, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Nicros, this question is off-topic for SO according to [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) -- "Questions asking to recommend a book, tool, library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." I'd recommend getting started with building an app, and asking a question if/when you get stuck. A good question includes a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you are looking for but these are links to some CRUD tutorials with react.

[Simple CRUD App](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/building-a-simple-crud-app-with-react-redux-part-1/)  by Sophie

[Step by Step React CRUD](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2016/07/react-crud-tutorial.html)

[Full-Stack React-Graphql CRUD APP](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/full-stack-react-graphql-tutorial-582ac8d24e3b)